# Searching in a cell Right to Left but stopping at the first instance

Tags: microsoft-excel, find

I have column A with "Customer Name-Account Number (Serial-number)". So, an example could look like:

```
ABC-12345 (1s39-a29a-23sh-akjf).
```

What I'm trying to get is just the customer name "ABC".

The serial number is a constant character list so I've used:

```
=LEFT(A14, LEN(A14)-39)
```

Which will return "ABC-12345".  But the customer numbers (12345) have slightly different character lengths.

So I have used the formula:

```
=LEFT(A14,FIND("-",A14)-1)
```

To give me everything left of the dash "-".

However, some of the company names may also include a "-".  So, instead of "J-Systems-12345" I'm getting "J".

Is there anyway to look right to left but stop looking at the first "-" that is found and return everything left of that "-"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Serial number length is fixed we can use this formula which will find the last `-` before the serial number and use that to limit the LEFT() function:

```
 =LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","}}}",LEN(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-22))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-22),"-",""))))-1)
```

I had to change the `-39` to `-22` as the data provided the serial is only 22 characters.  You may need to put it back to `-39` for your real data.

[image]

Comment: Scott, absolute perfection. Thank you so much, I would never have gotten there on my own!! That's worked perfectly! Can't thank you enough!

Comment: sorry about that, first time asking! Thanks so much again.